# Pandas - Merge DataFrame to Series when all column values are the same.

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I just started to using pandas and I would to reduce amount of data that I get by merging my DataFrames in that way:

- Load df
- Check in which columns all values are the same
- Delete other columns
- Reduce df to single Series
- Return

  ```
  def merge_df(in_df):
      alist = []
      for col in in_df.columns:
           if len(in_df[col].unique()) == 1:
           alist.append(col)
      return in_df[alist].T.squeeze()[1]
  ```

Is there any more elegent way to do it? E.g. without looping through all columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you can remove duplicate data by pandas simple function.
`df.drop_duplicates()` 
You can refer documentation [here.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

For removing particular column redundant data you can pass column name as a parameter "**subset**". It will remove whole row for duplicate data.